# rename original file by removing part of its name in bash

Tags: bash

Consider the filenames :

```
10249_sample1Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
10249_sample2Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
10249_sample3Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
10249_sample4Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
10249_sample5Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
10249_sample6Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
10249_sample7Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
10249_sample8Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
10249_sample9Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
10249_sample10Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
10249_sample11Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
10249_sample12Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
10249_sample13Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
10249_sample14Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
10249_sample15Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
10249_sample16Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
```

How would I remove `Aligned.sortedByCoord.out` from each file recursively and leave the rest intact ?

Comment: Use the `rename` command with a pattern substitution that replaces `Aligned.sortedByCoord.out` with an empty string.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash  
list_of_main_files=$(ls) #List of files saved in variable.
for file_name in $list_of_main_files
do
        echo "$file_name changes from original to"
        new_file_name=$( echo "$file_name" | sed -r 's/Aligned.sortedByCoord.out//g')
        echo "new file name $new_file_name "
        mv "$file_name" "$new_file_name"  #move old files in new file
done
echo "File Rename is Done:"
```

Comment: No need to involve `sed` for renaming files, a `for` loop and `mv` plus Parameter Expansion is enough.

Comment: @K.D Singh: It is useful to wait with the answer until the questioner has shown what he has done to answer the question himself.